# Entity Framework 4.1 RC: Override name of Many to Many join table

Tags: entity-framework, fluent-interface, entity-framework-4.1

In my code I have a many to many relationship defined using:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .HasMany( p => p.Authors ).WithMany();
```

Post.Authors is an ICollection of User entities.

The ModelBuilder automatically creates a table called **PostUsers**.

How can I override the table naming convention so that the ModelBuilder names the table **PostAuthors** when the database is created from the model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>
    .HasMany(p => p.Authors)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => m.ToTable("PostAuthors", "dbo"));
```

Comment: I have updated the question to be clearer - I do not want to  use an existing table named PostAuthors, but have the ModelBuilder create the table with that name (by default the convention names the table PostUsers).